# Tons of unmet dependencies when trying to install WINE Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, package-management, wine

Basically this is a quite common problem, but the suggestions I found haven't worked for me.

```
sudo apt-get install wine
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 brasero-cdrkit : Depends: libbrasero-media3-1 (= 3.10.0-0ubuntu1) but it is not going to be installed
 friends-twitter : Depends: friends
                   Depends: account-plugin-twitter but it is not going to be installed
 gir1.2-packagekitglib-1.0 : Depends: libpackagekit-glib2-16 (>= 0.8.12) but it is not going to be installed
 indicator-datetime : Depends: libecal-1.2-16 (>= 3.7.90) but it is not going to be installed
                      Depends: libedataserver-1.2-18 (>= 3.5.91) but it is not going to be installed
                      Recommends: indicator-applet but it is not going to be installed or
                                  indicator-renderer
                      Recommends: evolution-data-server but it is not going to be installed
                      Recommends: geoclue-ubuntu-geoip but it is not going to be installed or
                                  geoclue-provider
 indicator-network : Depends: unity8 (>= 7.82) but it is not going to be installed
 kdelibs5-plugins : Depends: libkdewebkit5 (= 4:4.13.0-0ubuntu1) but it is not going to be installed
 libaccounts-qt5-1 : Depends: libaccounts-glib0 (>= 1.14) but it is not going to be installed
 libldap-2.4-2 : Depends: libgssapi3-heimdal (>= 1.4.0+git20110226) but it is not going to be installed
 libnice10 : Depends: libgupnp-igd-1.0-4 (>= 0.2.1) but it is not going to be installed
 libnm-util2 : Depends: libnss3 (>= 2:3.13.4-2~) but it is not going to be installed or
                        libnss3-1d (>= 3.12.0~1.9b1) but it is not going to be installed
 liboauth0 : Depends: libnss3 (>= 2:3.13.4-2~) but it is not going to be installed or
                      libnss3-1d (>= 3.12.0~1.9b1) but it is not going to be installed
 libpeas-1.0-0 : Depends: libpython2.7 (>= 2.7) but it is not going to be installed
                 Depends: libpython3.4 (>= 3.4~b1) but it is not going to be installed
 libpython-dev : Depends: libpython2.7-dev (>= 2.7.5-1~) but it is not going to be installed
 libpython-stdlib : Depends: libpython2.7-stdlib (>= 2.7.5-1~) but it is not going to be installed
 libpython3-stdlib : Depends: libpython3.4-stdlib (>= 3.4.0-0~) but it is not going to be installed
 libreoffice-core : Depends: libnss3 (>= 2:3.13.4-2~) but it is not going to be installed or
                             libnss3-1d (>= 3.12.0~1.9b1) but it is not going to be installed
 librpm3 : Depends: librpmio3 (>= 4.11.0.1) but it is not going to be installed
 librpmbuild3 : Depends: librpmio3 (>= 4.11.0.1) but it is not going to be installed
 librpmsign1 : Depends: librpmio3 (>= 4.10.0) but it is not going to be installed
 libsmbclient : Depends: samba-libs (= 2:4.1.6+dfsg-1ubuntu2.14.04.9) but it is not going to be installed
 network-manager-gnome : Depends: network-manager (>= 0.9.8) but it is not going to be installed
                         Recommends: notification-daemon
 plasma-scriptengine-javascript : Depends: libplasma3 (>= 4:4.7.0) but it is not going to be installed
 python-dev : Depends: python2.7-dev (>= 2.7.5-1~) but it is not going to be installed
 python2.7 : Depends: libpython2.7-stdlib (= 2.7.6-8ubuntu0.2) but it is not going to be installed
 python3.4 : Depends: libpython3.4-stdlib (= 3.4.0-2ubuntu1.1) but it is not going to be installed
 qtdeclarative5-ubuntu-ui-toolkit-plugin : Depends: libqt5svg5 but it is not going to be installed
                                           Depends: libthumbnailer0 (>= 1.0) but it is not going to be installed
 rpm-common : Depends: librpmio3 (>= 4.10.0) but it is not going to be installed
 rpm2cpio : Depends: librpmio3 (>= 4.10.0) but it is not going to be installed
 signon-plugin-password : Depends: signond but it is not going to be installed
 system-config-printer-gnome : Depends: python-libxml2 but it is not going to be installed
 telepathy-haze : Depends: libpurple0 (>= 1:2.7.0) but it is not going to be installed
 telepathy-logger : Depends: libtelepathy-logger3 (= 0.8.0-3) but it is not going to be installed
 ubuntu-sso-client : Depends: python-ubuntu-sso-client (= 13.10-0ubuntu6) but it is not going to be installed
 unity-scope-mediascanner2 : Depends: libmediascanner-2.0-0 but it is not going to be installed
                             Depends: mediascanner2.0 but it is not going to be installed
 whoopsie-preferences : Depends: libwhoopsie0 but it is not going to be installed
 wine : Depends: wine1.6 but it is not going to be installed or
                 wine1.8 but it is not going to be installed
 yelp : Depends: libwebkitgtk-3.0-0 (>= 1.3.10) but it is not going to be installed
        Depends: libyelp0 (= 3.10.2-0ubuntu1) but it is not going to be installed
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
```

I tried stuff like adding official ubuntu and wine repositories (+ sudo apt-get update). Then I tried removing every reporsitory in sources.list and sources.list.d and only having the official/default ones. I don't think I have held packages, as I get no output for

```
sudo dpkg --get-selections | grep hold
```

I'm not sure what has happened to my Ubuntu installation, especially I'm not the only person using this system.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I just tried

```
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get autoclean
```

and this seems to have helped. Then installing wine seems to be going without a problem. I knew the commands but I forgot to try them actually...

A stupid mistake. However, since I did quite a lot of googling and browsing askubuntu and did stumble on "autoclean/clean" hours lates it might be not a bad idea to leave this question up for the next person, but the community can decide.